# (Shell Script) Set value of numbers from current time

Tags: bash, shell, time

**(Shell Script) Set value of numbers from current time**

Im trying to make a shell script to take the output from the current time (HH:MM) and assign a variable (font) to each number 0-9. This essentially is a clock, which I need to run in realtime (changes when the time changes). for example if I run this command:

```
date +"%T"
```

I will get an output (results may vary):

```
12:30:27
```

How can I make it so instead it will output this (without the "seconds")

```
  _ ____        _____  ___  
 / |___ \   _  |___ / / _ \ 
 | | __) | (_)   |_ \| | | |
 | |/ __/   _   ___) | |_| |
 |_|_____| (_) |____/ \___/
```

The only way I can think of achieving this is by assigning the numbers individually with the font being used. The link to the font i am using is:

http://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&f=Standard&t=12%20%3A%2030

Is there anyway I can output the time (in realtime) using numbers like this?

Comment: Perhaps `man date` will point you in the right direction. There are many more options besides %T for output formatting. Many many many more.

Answer (score 2):

To show a realtime ASCII art clock, use

```
watch 'date "+%H:%M" | figlet'
```

to save the current time in a variable, use

```
myVariable="$(date "+%H:%M" | figlet)"
```

Comment: When I run this, it works, however it goes into it's own process which I have to press Ctrl+C to exit. Is there any way around that?

Comment: I thought you wanted a real-time wall-clock that gets updated. But if you just want a single shot time-stamp, just run it without the `watch`.

Comment: I did, I just was wondering if It could be viewed within a script that doesnt require Ctrl+C to exit out of it

Comment: Well... you can replace the `watch` with a loop but obviously you still need some way to break the loop. A _Press_ _any_ _key_ variant could be something like this: `while ! read -n1 -t 3; do clear; date "+%H:%M" | figlet ; done`

Answer (score 0):

As long as your cursor is not at the bottom of the screen, and you are in a terminal emulator that supports these cursor motions:

```
#!/bin/sh


f() { echo -n "\\033[$1D\\033[1B"; } 
_c="  _$(f 2)(_)$(f 2)_$(f 2)(_)$(f 1) "
_0="  ___$(f 4)/ _ \\ $(f 7)| | | |$(f 7)| |_| |$(f 6)\\___/  "
_1=" _$(f 2)/ |$(f 3)| |$(f 3)| |$(f 3)|_| "
_2=" ____$(f 5)|___ \\ $(f 5)__) | $(f 7)/ __/  $(f 8)|_____| "
_3=" _____$(f 6)|___ / $(f 7)  |_ \\ $(f 7) ___) | $(f 9)|____/  "
_4="  _  _   $(f 10) | || |   $(f 10) | || |_  $(f 10) |__   _| $(f 7) |_|   "
_5="  ____   $(f 9) | ___|  $(f 9) |___ \  $(f 9)  ___) | $(f 9) |____/  "
_6="  __    $(f 9) / /_   $(f 9)| '_ \  $(f 9)| (_) | $(f 9) \___/  "
_7=" _____ $(f 9) |___  | $(f 9)    / /  $(f 9)   / /   $(f 9)  /_/   "
_8="  ___  $(f 9) ( _ ) $(f 9) / _ \ $(f 9)| (_) |$(f 9) \___/  "
_9="   ___  $(f 9)  / _ \ $(f 9) | (_) |$(f 9)  \__, |$(f 7)   /_/  "

eval echo -e '"'$(date +"%T" | tr : c | cut -b 1-5 | sed 's/./${_&}\\033[4A/g')'"'
echo -e "\\033[5B"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Host@User> date +"%H:%M"
09:47
Host@User>
```

Comment: This answer attempt is missing the ASCII art output part.